# How to sum negative numbers in a pivot table using calculated fields?

Tags: excel

I've got some accounts data that I'm trying to manipulate and present but I can't seem to figure this out... I've got an "Amounts" (£) column (among many others) that I've put into a pivot table and I'm trying to use the calculated field function to separate the minuses (income) from the positives (expenses), but it won't allow me to when I enter the formula. Any suggestions? [*without manipulating the source data!*]

So, I've already tried entering the formula: `=IF(Amount<0, Amount, 0)` for income (as a negative would be, in my case, an income). I've also tried `=Amount<0` and `=IF(Amount<0, Amount*1, 0)`, but none seem to work at all. SOS!